# Fullcalendar: How to add 'link' item to custom button

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a doubt in fullcalendar. I am also a beginner to it. I am having a custom button and what I want now is 'on click' of the     button it should go to a new page. It shall be added through a anchor tag from normal `<html>` buttons. But, I could not grab how to do it using a custom button in full calendar

The full-calendar script is as:-

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
      customButtons: {
        EventButton: {
            text:'Add Event',
            click:function(event, jsEvent, view){
                   $('#modal_calendar').modal('show');
          }
        }
      },

    utc: true, 
    header: { 
    left: 'prev,next today EventButton', 
    center: 'title', 
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' 
    },   
   }
   });
```

[image]

Comment: I deleted my answer because it doesn't answer your question. With the click property of EventButton being a function you can write whatever Javascript you want. As ADyson said in your other question there are a number of ways to achieve showing a custom dialog form. You can certainly do this via ajax, what's your preferred method of showing a custom dialog? Just do it as you normally would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know wether I'm guessing right or not. But I assume you just want navigate to another page when clicking on your Eventbutton.
Just use the "window.location.href" property. This navigates you to the URL given there.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
       customButtons: {
          EventButton: {
          text:'Add Event',
          click:function(event, jsEvent, view){
               window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
          }
       }
     },
     utc: true, 
     header: { 
       left: 'prev,next today EventButton', 
       center: 'title', 
       right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' 
     },   
  })
});
```